# How to tell the season by specified range of dates

Tags: php, arrays, date, range

I'm going to specify the season by dates given. I have 4 seasons ranging by dates (not by month). So I decided to use `in_array` and `range()` but it shows nothing.

Here's my code:

```
$p1=strtotime("2013-12-13");
$p2=strtotime("2014-02-20");
$h1a=strtotime("2014-02-21");
$h1b=strtotime("2014-04-31");
$l1=strtotime("2013-05-01");
$l2=strtotime("2013-10-31");
$h2a=strtotime("2013-11-01");
$h2b=strtotime("2013-12-19");


$today=strtotime(date("Y-m-d"));

if(in_array($today, range($p1, $p2))){
    echo "peak";
}elseif(in_array($today, range($h1a, $h1b))){
    echo "hi1";
}elseif(in_array($today, range($l1, $l2))){
    echo "low";
}else(in_array($today, range($h2a, $h2b))){
    echo "h2";
}
```

Could you guys please improve my code.

Regards,

Comment: Because you memory limit is exceeding because of range. I used only 2 days in range http://codepad.viper-7.com/PLFObE and it shows that much of output.

Comment: Is there any better way to test the current date to the season?

Comment: See answer with greater than and less than.

Answer (score 1):

Because you memory limit is exceeding because of range. I used only 2 days in range http://codepad.viper-7.com/PLFObE and it shows that much of output.

You can use greater than and less than to measure the date.

```
if($today >= $p1 && $today <= $p2){
    echo "peak";
}elseif($today >= $h1a && $today <= $h1b){
    echo "hi1";
}elseif($today >= $l1 && $today <= $l2){
    echo "low";
}else($today >= $h2a && $today <= $h2b){
    echo "h2";
}
```

**Edit**

[Codepad](http://codepad.org/7dMiIcKe)

Comment: Yogesh, your code looks nicer but not work. It's not returns "low" as I expected.

Comment: @Wilf See edited answer. Just used comparison in wrong order. :)

Answer (score 1):

I've got my own solution now. Thanks for those trials. The code was adapted from : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/php/change-graphics-based-on-season/

```
<?
function current_season() {
       // Locate the icons
       $icons = array(
               "peak" => "peak season",
               "low" => "low season",
               "high1" => "high1 season",
               "high2" => "high2 season"
       );

       // What is today's date - number
       $day = date("z");

       //  Days of peak
       $peak_starts = date("z", strtotime("December 13"));
       $peak_ends   = date("z", strtotime("February 20"));

       //  Days of low
       $low_starts = date("z", strtotime("May 1"));
       $low_ends   = date("z", strtotime("October 31"));

       //  Days of high
       $high_starts = date("z", strtotime("February 21"));
       $high_ends   = date("z", strtotime("April 31"));

       //  If $day is between the days of peak, low, high, and winter
       if( $day >= $peak_starts && $day <= $peak_ends ) :
               $season = "peak";
       elseif( $day >= $low_starts && $day <= $low_ends ) :
               $season = "low";
       elseif( $day >= $high1_starts && $day <= $high1_ends ) :
               $season = "high";
       else :
               $season = "high2";
       endif;

       $image_path = $icons[$season];

       echo $image_path;
}
echo current_season();
?>
```